# How to get parameter value from body in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, http-post, payment-gateway

We are integrating payment gateway in VueJs application, everything working fine. But while navigating from payment page (third party) to Vue component the response data is passed in body. How we can get it in Vue component created() method?

Comment: How user navigating from payment to your site? Via callback url? Then I guess the url should be like: yoursite.com?abc=xyz? Right?

Comment: If it's a redirect the parameters will be in query string, right ?

Comment: No from UI we are integrating payment gateway api, the api will take care of payment then it navigates to Vue page(which has been provided to api as a return url) the url looks like http://localhost:8081/pageName, it is navigating correctly and response i can see in console network tab.

Comment: I guess the `localhost:8081/pageName` is handled by your backend first. You should get the response body there, and redirect (with query string parameter contain payment response) to your Vue route. Like this: `localhost:8081/pageName?key=<payment body>`. Then in Vue component, you can parse URL and get the `key` param.

Comment: Ok, i will try. thank you.